# Creating imageCollection for each date from a table in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

In my AOI there are 8 different Firms alarms on different places, which are available as a table (Feature Collection). Now I want to create an image collection that displays the last five images and the next five images for each date. Is this possible?

Here is my Code:

```
var FIRMS_filtered = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS')
.filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
.filterBounds(AOI)
.select('T21')
// Create a list of start days
var dayOfYearList = ee.List.sequence(1, 365, 5)
// Function to convert day to date
var dateFromDayOfYear = function(day) {
var dateString = ee.String('2018').cat(ee.String(ee.Number(day).toInt()))
return ee.Date.parse('YYYYD', dateString)
}
// Create a list of start dates
var startDateList = dayOfYearList.map(dateFromDayOfYear)
// Function to return an image consisting of count of valid pixels in the date range
var checkDateRange = function(start) {
var end = ee.Date(start).advance(5, 'day')
var dateRangeFiltered = FIRMS_filtered.filter(ee.Filter.date(start, end))
var pixelCount = dateRangeFiltered.reduce(ee.Reducer.count())
// return the image with a new property for start date
  return pixelCount.set({start_date: start})
}

// Count total pixels within AOI
var totalPixelCountAOI = function(image) {
 var countDict = ee.Image(image).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: AOI,
scale: 500})
var totalCount = countDict.get('T21_count')
// Create a featurecollection with null geometry
// featurecollection helps because you can filter by properties
return ee.Feature(null, {'date': ee.Image(image).get('start_date'), 'totalCount': totalCount})
}
  // Map the functions over all dates
  var yearImages = startDateList.map(checkDateRange);
  var yearCounts = ee.FeatureCollection(yearImages.map(totalPixelCountAOI))
  // Apply filter on results
 var rangesWithNoFiresAOI = yearCounts.filter(ee.Filter.eq('totalCount', 0))
 // Ranges with fire
  var rangesWithFiresAOI = yearCounts.filter(ee.Filter.gt('totalCount', 0))
 print(rangesWithFiresAOI.aggregate_array('date'))
```

At the moment, I get an imageCollection for the whole year 2018. I think I have to create a loop for each date in the table, but I dont know.

```
  var table = ee.FeatureCollection(rangesWithFiresAOI);
  print ('table is', table)
  var Sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
              .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
              // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
              .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
              .map(maskS2clouds)
              .filterBounds(bounds_AOI)
              .map(function(image){return image.clip(bounds_AOI)});
```